# Power plug identification, AMP possibly?

Tags: amplifier, connector

So I need a plug for a Gehl CT7-23 telehandler that had a partial wiring fire. I've found all the Deutsch and similar plugs, but am stuck on this one:

[image]

It has AMP on the side. I should have taken more photos and measurements on-site, but didn't realize it will be so difficult to locate this plug. I'd say the terminals are about 0.25" wide. If you observe, 2 of the corners are beveled and 2 are square. It also has a bulge on the side toward the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [TE "Fastin/Faston" housing](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/terminals-splices/terminal-housings-insulation-sleeves-and-blocks.html?tab=pgp-story) for 6.3 mm wide quick-connect female disconnects.

That particular housing is a [TE 180900](https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/180900/2054251).

[image: TE 180900]

{Source: TE}

You'll have to buy the quick-connect female contacts separately, depending on the wire gauge. For example: https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/180384-2/1131475